# Does cygserver improve Cygwin performance? If so, with what tasks?

Tags: performance, cache, cygwin, caching

I've read that cygserver [can improve performance in some circumstances](https://superuser.com/a/1183283) but I'm not really clear on how - or on how to know whether it's applicable to our use case.

Can anyone provide any insights?

Answer (score 1):

The major effect on performance is the cache of network credentials

From  https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygserver.html

> What is Cygserver?
>
> Cygserver is a program which is designed to run as a background
> service. It provides Cygwin applications with services which require
> security arbitration or which need to persist while no other cygwin
> application is running.
>
> The implemented services so far are:
>
> ```
> XSI IPC Message Queues.
>
> XSI IPC Semaphores.
>
> XSI IPC Shared Memory.
> ```
>
> Allows non-privileged users to store obfuscated passwords in the registry to be used by setuid and seteuid calls to create user tokens
> with network credentials. This service is used by passwd -R. Using the
> stored passwords in set(e)uid does not require running Cygserver. For
> details, see the section called “Switching the user context”.